# Query some parent data and its child data in Laravel 8

Tags: sql, laravel, controller, subquery, relationship

I have a personnel table which is connected to other tables. One of its child table is BMI. A personnel has many BMI record. At the moment I have this query.

```
$personnel = Personnel::join('personnel_training', function($join) use ($request){
                $join->on('personnel.id', '=', 'personnel_training.personnel_id')
                ->where('personnel_training.training_id', $request->training); 
            })
            ->join('state', 'personnel.state_id', '=', 'state.id')
            ->join('unit', 'state.unit_id', '=', 'unit.id')
            ->select('state.name as statename','unit.name as unitname','personnel.*','personnel_training.training_id')
                    ->selectRaw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DATE(birth_date), current_date) AS age")
                    ->selectRaw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DATE(date_lastprom), current_date) AS sample")
                    ->orderBy('last_name', 'asc')
                    ->paginate(50)
                    ->appends(request()
                    ->query());
```

My code is working fine at the moment. The thing I want to accomplish is to connect the bmi and personnel table and get latest record of personnel BMI. What are the things I need to add? I already tried other way but I have no luck. I am thinking that maybe subquery will give me the data I want but I don't know how to do it. I already  connect the personnel and bmi model to have a one to many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

So you want simply to access the relationship of them all... don't take my comment as harsh but please, read the documentation, it is more complex to create the code you are showing us than doing what the documentation says...

You have to do this:

```php
Personnel::with(['personnelTraining', 'state', 'unit'])->orderBy('last_name')->paginate(50)->appends(request()->query());
```

Then in your blade you have to process the missing `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, it would be `$personnel->birth_date->diffInYears($personnel->current_date)`, same for `date_lastprom`.

I have no idea what `request()->query()` will do...

Comment: thanks mate. This functionality is used for filtering personnel based on the training selected. The process is I have to select a training and the system will show all personnel who already undergo with those training. I think I cannot use what you suggest since i believe it will show all personnel with our without a child record.

Comment: Then change `with` to `has` and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

In your personnel model have this relationship function

```
return $this->hasMany('Personnel', 'personnel_id');
     ->order_by('date', 'desc')
     ->limit(5);
```